# TS(2322) Error When Using Observable In Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm new to Angular 12 framework. I'm following a tutorial that uses the `Observable` class to query on fixed data asynchronously; I'm getting `ts(2322)` error due to version differences caused by using Angular 8 in training. A summary of the service, module and data source is available below:

```js
/* movie.service.ts */
export class MovieService
{  
    ...
    getMovie( id: number ) : Observable<Movie>
    {
        /* TS(2322) error occurs in the following line of code. */
        return of( Movies.find( movie => movie.id === id ) );
    }
}

/* movie.datasource.ts */
import { Movie } from "./movie";

export const Movies: Movie[] = [
    { id: 1, name: "movie1", imageUrl: "1.jpg" },
    { id: 2, name: "movie2", imageUrl: "2.jpg" }
];

/* movie.ts */
export class Movie 
{
    id!: number;
    name!: string;
    imageUrl!: string;
}
```

The `getMovie()` method in file `movie.service.ts` outputs the following error:

```
Type 'Observable<Movie | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Movie>'.
  Type 'Movie | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Movie'.ts(2322)
```

I'm aware that this problem is caused by type-safe rules of TypeScript. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error is self-describable. `Movies.find()` can return a movie if found or `undefined` otherwise. The simplest way to accommodate is to expect exactly that:

```
getMovie( id: number ) : Observable<Movie | undefined>
{
    return of( Movies.find( movie => movie.id === id ) );
}
```

Alternatively, you can check for result of `find()`, and if it is null - return a `new Movie()` or throw exception

Comment: During my research, I realized that the method will be defined as `getMovie( id: number ) : Observable<Movie | null | undefined >` and the error will be fixed. However, what I don't understand is, isn't it the client's responsibility to control the data returned by the `getMovie()` method? How does this use relate to TypeScript's type-safe rules?

Comment: Or return empty observable.. it all depends OP use case

Comment: @SercanSebetçi - relates directly! you can't ignore the return type of `find()` which can be `null` (not found)

Comment: In this way, I also learned that the problem isn't caused by the version difference in Angular framework. Thank you so much.